# Chrome/IE problem with absolute positioning of multiple divs with images

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, position, html

Right now I am helping a friend flesh out an idea about displaying various apparel images inside a 400x400 box.

I am having a problem with the use of absolutely positioned divs (outfit-box-pants, out-fit-box-shirts, etc.) that contain the apparel images inside a parent div(outfit-box) with position set to relative. On Firefox, all my divs line up correctly, and the site displays as it should. But on IE and Chrome, my absolute position divs are making a mess of the entire page.

The problem seems to be that IE/Chrome are assigning some kind of positioning to the rest of my divs that is causing them to all scrunch up. What's going on?

Edit: problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image tags are missing a closing tag (`/>`).

```
                <div class="outfit-box-shoes">
                    <img src="http://preview.archerandreed.com/images/outfits/large/shoes-001.png" />
                </div>                    
                <div class="outfit-box-shirt">
                    <img src="http://preview.archerandreed.com/images/outfits/large/shirt-001.png" />
                </div>                    
                <div class="outfit-box-pants">
                    <img src="http://preview.archerandreed.com/images/outfits/large/pants-001.png" />
                </div>
```

Once I added those, the images lined up for me (http://jsfiddle.net/sSRVe/9/).

Answer (score 1):

I looked at it in firefox 5.  It's a mess there too...

I think you need to look at it with firebug.  For example, it says you have a "styles.css" file that redefines .outfix-box-pants to be at left: 1px, top 1px.  (line 297)

So, actually everything is displaying exactly as you've defined it.

You might want to either remove the reference to http://preview.archerandreed.com/styles.css or fix it.

Now, as to why your firefox is displaying correctly, I'd say it is cached and you're not looking at the current copy.

Comment: Looks a mess in IE, FF, Chrome, Opera...  yikes.